# JSF: Dynamically change form

Tags: ajax, forms, jsf, jsf-2, tomahawk

I want to build a form that dynamically changes the components visible depending on the state of other components.

For example... There are some text boxes and some check boxes, and if the user activates a certain check box, a bunch of other input elements should appear.

Can I do this with JSF 2.0 + Tomahawk or do I have to get another library to do this? And how can I do it? This won't work without AJAX, will it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ajax is a convenient way to do this and JSF 2.0 comes with ajax bundled.

Here is an example:

```
<h:selectOneRadio value="#{a7.myCheckbox.state}">
      <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{bundle.yes}" itemValue="1"/>
      <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{bundle.no}" itemValue="0"/>
      <f:ajax render="uawGroup"/>
</h:selectOneRadio>

<h:panelGroup id="uawGroup" layout="block">
   <h:outputText value="#{bundle.wichmed}"
        rendered="#{a7.myCheckbox.state == 1}"/>
   <h:inputText value="#{}" id="myInput"
        rendered="#{a7.myCheckbox.state == 1}"/> 
</h:panelGroup>
```

The `h:panelGroup` will be rendered when "yes"-option is clicked in `h:selectOneRadio` (itemValue == 1). Initially it is 0 (set in the bean "a7").

The `h:panelGroup` acts as wrapper since you can only update components with ajax that are actually rendered on the page (`h:outputText` and `h:inputText` are initially not displayed).

Comment: This is great, thanks! But how does it work if I want to display a certain set of components if a h:button was clicked? Thank you!

Comment: To make it clear what I'm trying to do: I have some panelGrids and I want the user to go through them step by step (fill in the the stuff in grid1, press the button which makes grid2 appear, and so on). How can I achieve this? And can I already let the server process certain inputs of grid1 to display results in grid2?

Comment: @geeehhdaa You can put the `f:ajax` inside an `h:commandButton` as well. Use the `execute` attribute to process input fields during ajax calls: `<f:ajax render="ids of components to be re-rendered" execute="ids of components to be processed">`

Comment: Thank you! The problem is though, that I want those panelGroups to be initially invisible. So the effect should not cause stuff to process, it should only make the next panelGroups visible. How should I choose the render attribute of the groups that should appear only if the button was clicked then? The button has no state, has it? Edit: Actually one of the buttons should call some action. How can I AJAX-call an action?