# How to change h:outputText value by JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jsf

I already tested with 2 inputText, It runs well
for example

```
var tdate = document.getElementById('txtDate');    //h:inputText
var tdt = document.getElementById('txtDateTime');  //h:inputText

tdate.onchange = function(){
  tdt.value = tdate.value;
};
```

How can I change the value of " tdt " - h:outputText?

```
var tdate = document.getElementById('txtDate');    //h:inputText
var tdt = document.getElementById('txtDateTime');  //h:outputText
```

Comment: this link can be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5654269/jsf-dynamically-change-form

Comment: Its the same way. Its not working for output text?

Comment: yes, not working for output text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look in the generated HTML source. Rightclick page in browser and *view source*. You'll see that the `<h:outputText>` renders a HTML `<span>` element with the value in its body. To alter the body of a `<span>` in JavaScript you need to manipulate the [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM%3aelement.innerHTML).

```
tdt.innerHTML = "new value";
```