# Ajax is fired first and then setter is invoked

Tags: jsf

I have the below code:

```
<h:selectOneRadio value="#{exampleController.Status}" layout="pageDirection">
  <f:selectItem itemLabel="Non-Tax Resident" itemValue="NON_TAX_RESIDENT" />
  <f:selectItem itemLabel="Tax Resident" itemValue="TAX_RESIDENT"/>
  <f:ajax event="click" render="statusID"/>
</h:selectOneRadio>

<input id="statusID" value="#{bean.enteredValue}"/>
```

When i select the radio button, i want the value to be saved in the bean and then the ajax call to run.
But when i run this code, i see the ajax call being run first.

Could someone let me know what has  to be changed?

Comment: Why are you using the "click" event?

Comment: @JasperdeVries : on radio button selection, i want to render a component. Hence using the click event.

Comment: Sorry about that.. "click" is indeed correct for radio buttons (it's even "click" by default so it could be omitted).

Comment: yes click is the default event for radio button. But i want to know why value="#{exampleController.Status}" does not set the radio button selection to status.

Comment: @Santosh maybe this can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12717060/hselectoneradio-doesnt-work-with-ajax-change-event